# Call php file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm attempting to use this [guide](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) to use AJAX to make changes to a form. It's not working and I'm having difficulties troubleshooting. My current code:

**Base page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_find_location.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="countries" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a country:</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">Canada</option>
<option value="3">China</option>
<option value="4">Viet Nam</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Country info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**demo_find_location.php**

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
echo $q;
?>
```

The onchange function is being triggered since the div with `id="textHint"` is being reset when the select option `value = ""`. It doesn't seem to be processing the php of my php file. Could it be a pathing issue or code incompatibility? I'm currently using the */var/www/html/sites/all/libraries* directory to contain my php file.

Comment: You shouldn't have `</body></html>` in the PHP script.

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to troubleshoot this. You should be able to find the AJAX request and see what the response contains.

Comment: The code on w3schools.com is wrong. The PHP script shouldn't return an entire HTML page, it should just return the HTML that should be put inside the result `<div>`.

Comment: Everything outside `<?php ... ?>` should be removed from that example. Junk like this is why we avoid recommending w3schools.

Comment: Press F12 in the browser and look for console tab

Answer (score -1):

This.value is null? If the function is getting called by the onchange event and texting is getting reset it's because the passed string(str) = "".

Comment: It passes null when there is nothing to pass. Otherwise, it attempts to pass a value to a page that isn't found (it's a pathing issue). I need to look into it more.

Comment: change this <select name="countries" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> to this: <select name="countries" onchange="showUser('hello')">

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var baseUrl="this is your website path";
         //
        // http://localhost/websitefolder/path or http://livepath
       //
        var eleTxtHint = document.getElementById("txtHint");
        function showUser(str)
        {
            eleTxtHint.innerHTML="";
            if (str!="") 
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else 
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
                {
                    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                        var response=JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        if(response.status==true)
                        {
                            eleTxtHint.innerHTML=this.responseText;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            alert('somethings went wrong');
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('somethings went wrong');
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("GET",baseUrl+"demo_find_location.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();`enter code here`
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="countries" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select a country:</option>
                <option value="1">USA</option>
                <option value="2">Canada</option>
                <option value="3">China</option>
                <option value="4">Viet Nam</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Country info will be listed here.</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**demo_find_location.php**

```
<?php
$q = isset($_GET['q'])?intval($_GET['q']):"";
echo json_encode(array('status'=>true,'data'=>$q));
exit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine, just Don't FORGET to load the jquery library in the header when using javascript/jquery codes

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
/// rest of your page
```

Also, here's a minified version of what you are currently trying to do that i hope it will help you understand jquery :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
/// We trigger the function onchange
function showUser()
{
// We get the value of the country
var q = document.getElementById("countries").value;
if(!isNaN(q))//We check if the value is a valid number
{
$("#txtHint").load("demo_find_location.php?q="+q);//We load the result in txtHint
}
}
</script> 
<form>
<select id="countries" onchange="showUser()">
<option value="">Select a country:</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">Canada</option>
<option value="3">China</option>
<option value="4">Viet Nam</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Country info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Comment: Why jquery is needed here? OP's code does not require jQuery to work.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind. I've fixed the pathing issue. Now I'm just worried about cross browser performance. jQuery might end up working better.